# How to read IHttpRequest to gain access to session in validation, on self-hosted ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

There are several posts on this. I'm on 3.9.71 by the way.

The first one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594881/access-servicstack-net-session-in-validator), answered by @Scott. In general, you can't really access the session using something similar to Service.SessionAs<> simply because validation kicks in before the service is even executed.

The second one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174149/isolating-accessing-set-session-information-within-custom-validator-servicestac), answered by @paaschpa. In here, there is a way to get hold of the session, even in the validation phase, since technically we have

- The `CacheClient`, which can be injected into the validator
- The underlying request, which will be retrieved internally within `SessionFeature.GetSessionKey()`. The method checks for ServiceStack's own `IHttpRequest`, failing which it will fallback on `HttpContext.Current.Request`. Obviously since we didn't pass anything into `SessionFeature.GetSessionKey()` the method goes for `HttpContext.Current.Request`, which is really ASP.NET specific.

Once you configure ServiceStack for self-hosted mode, this fails since we don't have `HttpContext.Current.Request`. Following is the code that fails (`GetSessionId` is invoked by `GetSessionKey`).

```
public static string GetSessionId(IHttpRequest httpReq = null)
{
    if (httpReq == null && HttpContext.Current == null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Only ASP.NET Requests accessible via Singletons are supported");
    }
    httpReq = (httpReq ?? HttpContext.Current.Request.ToRequest(null));
    return httpReq.GetSessionId();
}
```

It seems to be a case of so close yet so far. Any way we can get hold of `IHttpRequest` in the validator?

**Update**

Looking at the `ValidationFilters.RequestFilter` action in ServiceStackV3, it seems like the intention is already there. Note how if the validator implements `IRequiresHttpRequest`, it injects the request into the validator.

```
public static class ValidationFilters
{
    public static void RequestFilter(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        var validator = ValidatorCache.GetValidator(req, requestDto.GetType());
        if (validator == null) return;

        var validatorWithHttpRequest = validator as IRequiresHttpRequest;
        if (validatorWithHttpRequest != null)
            validatorWithHttpRequest.HttpRequest = req;

        var ruleSet = req.HttpMethod;
        var validationResult = validator.Validate(
            new ValidationContext(requestDto, null, new MultiRuleSetValidatorSelector(ruleSet)));
```

I tried implementing the `IRequiresHttpRequest` interface on my validator, but unfortunately it is still null. Apparently this is due to a bug on my code, so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the update above, the trick is to ensure your validator implements `IRequiresHttpRequest`, and you're good to go!

```
public MyDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<MyDto>, IRequiresHttpRequest
```

The validation filter will then inject the request on your behalf as it fires up the validator. You can then get the request via the property `HttpRequest`. I've tested this on a simpler solution, and it worked.